# How to override ASP.Net MVC's default model binder so that an empty value bound to a non-nullable value type won't trigger a model validation error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

Something I've found quite frustrating in ASP.Net MVC is that the default model binder implicitly applies the `Required` annotation when binding an empty (string or null) value to a non-nullable value type instead of simply leaving the target with its default value, or at least providing an option to allow that to be the default behaviour.

Given a scenario where it's inconvenient to change the target property type on the model to a nullable value, what's the shortest amount of code I can employ to allow the default model binder to simply skip its attempt to bind an empty value to a non-nullable value type? I'm assuming I'll need to subclass `DefaultModelBinder`, but I'm not sure what I need to override to achieve the desired behaviour.

example:

```
<input type="text" name="MyField"/>
```

Submit without a value:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
{
    // do stuff
}

public class MyModel
{
    public int MyField { get; set; }
}
```

The property `MyField` should be allowed to retain its default value of `0` seeing as an empty value was posted from the form.

Assume that I can't simply change the property type a `Nullable<int>`.

Comment: i'm using mvc3; the behaviour you want occurs for me out of the box.
if the model binder is binding an 'empty' value what value is it binding?

Comment: The value posted is received as an empty string when the text box is blank. An empty string won't bind to (for example) a decimal type, because there's no conversion to handle it. I want the convention to be to simply not try to bind it.

Comment: thats not the behaviour i'm experiencing or i dont understand or i havent recreated your situation exactly. see this screenshot:
http://imgur.com/xXqib
I added `Field1` to my form and this is a POST using a query string

Comment: i should add that i am seeing the modelstate error you mention (`Field1` is required) server-side. I guess now looking at the title of your post this is what you're trying to avoid. :)
Are you using client-side javascript validation?

Comment: That's an option, though feels a bit dodgy, like I'm just trying to pretend the problem isn't there. If there's no other solution I'll go for it, though it would be nice if the user could just leave the fields blank that they don't care about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this? (**Disclaimer:** Not tested to any degree of confidence)

```
public class NonRequiredModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override object GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, IModelBinder propertyBinder)
    {
        var result = base.GetPropertyValue(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, propertyBinder);
        if (result == null && propertyDescriptor.PropertyType.IsValueType)
            return Activator.CreateInstance(propertyDescriptor.PropertyType);

        return result;
    }
}
```

The idea -- in theory -- is to determine what value the `DefaultModelBinder` assigned to the property, check if it was a null value and then assign it to the default value of the `ValueType` that is being bound.

This should prevent the binder from adding `ModelState` errors, and still would not affect the validation of other attributes such as `[Range]`

I would recommend taking this a step further and creating your own attribute (i.e., `NonRequiredAttribute`). Then in your custom model binder you could check to see if the property has the new `NonRequired` attribute, and execute this custom code **only** in the case that it does.